# Compiling for Windows SDK Version 8.1 and running on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows

I am compiling C++ DLLs (native code) to be loaded by Microsft Excel on Windows. No issues with it, everything is working fine as it should be.

I working with Windows 10 and was initially compiling it with the Windows SDK Version 10.0.12699.0.  Then I found out that to be able to run on Windows 7 I needed to compile with Windows SDK 8.1, which also worked fine.

My question: Is there any disadvanges on Targeting Windows SDK 8.1 for something that will be used mostly on Windows 10? I want to know it to decided if it´s worth providing different versions of the files.

Other thing, when should I care to update for the latest Windows 10 SDK? As long the older ones still work I am thinking that they would be my preference for they would work for the widest range of machines. Is there any issue on it that I need to be concerned?

Comment: sdk - this is only set of definitions for compiler (header files) and linker (lib files). new version of sdk/wdk - add new definitions. old is not changed. if/until you not use new functions - you can use old sdk. in practice no any  difference  which sdk you use (the binary will be the same - if source code/compiler/linker setting the same and you use the same compiler/linker)

Comment: unlike c crt - sdk/wdk - almost not use static libs - only import libs - as result no any difference from which sdk/wdk you use lib. and structures/functions in headers also not changed

Comment: Targeting one of the many Win10 sdk versions is only actually necessary when you write UWP apps or need to use Win10-specific functions.  Which you don't when you write a DLL for use in Excel.  Targeting 8.1 is fine, set the [WINVER macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt?view=vs-2019) to 0x601.  Only 4 more months before Win7 support ends, yay.